# Truncate all tables in Postgres with a suffix

Tags: postgresql

I have a set of tables with suffix `_ABC`

The table names are like:

```
TEST_ABC
MYTB_ABC
AB_1_ER_ABC
```

I know I can do:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE TEST_ABC;
```

But I don't want to run this 100s of times.

I have 100s of those. Is there a way using plain SQL(only 1 query) to truncate tables with suffix _ABC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need dynamic SQL for this. This can be done with an anonymous PL/pgSQL block:

```
do
$$
declare
  l_sql text;
begin
  select 'truncate '||string_agg(tablename, ',')||' cascade'
     into l_sql
  from pg_tables
  where tablename like '%\_abc' escape '\'
    and schemaname = 'public';
  execute l_sql;
end;
$$
```

Comment: shouldn't this also contain a db-nane check, could corrupt the db in case there are multiple dbs.